# List item Layout not showing items to full width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a custom list layout, Every thing works fine (custom class and list Adapter )........ But item on the activity is somehow not expanding to full screen.
This is my Layout design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chapter_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chapter_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />



        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Output]

I am trying to shift the arrow to right corner of the screen.
Any Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: woow. Thanks. Can you please elaborate why it doesn't work for constraint layout?

Answer (score 2):

For the arrow, remove the layout_weight and make its width wrap_content. Now, all the remaining weight should be used up by the chapter number+description and it should work.